# Iterating through hash table giving out TypeError

Tags: python, arrays, hash

I have an array based Hash Table and whenever i try to iterate over it by :

```
for i in hash_table:
    val = hash_table[i]
```

an example of an output when i print the hash table would be:

```
(Alex:2),(Ryan:4),(Clara:6)
```

Whenever i try to iterate through it with the code I've written above, it is giving me a statement 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable'. I'm so confused about this and I'll appreciate any help on this.

What I'm trying to do now is to print out only the values of each key in the hash table using the for loop above but the error message I'm constantly getting is always there.

Comment: @DavidG isn't i supposed to be the key? Example, Alex  :  2.The key would be alex and it's value is 2.  the hash_table[i] should be returning the value of the key but an error persist.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right. It would help if you could give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: This message 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable' is telling you that you think `hash_table` is a `dict`, but it isn't, it's an integer. Just before the `for` statement, put `print(hash_table)` and after that `print (dict)`. What does that tell you?

Comment: @BoarGules print(hash_table) prints out the output like in the example above while print(dict) prints out <class'dict'> followed by 0.0s. Does this imply i should treat it as an array instead of assuming it uses dictionary?

Comment: @BoarGules is there any suggestion on what i should edit in the for loop in order to gain access to the value?

Comment: `print (dict)` should produce `<class 'dict'>` *and nothing else*. `print(hash_table)` should produce {'Alex':2,'Ryan':4}. It looks like `hash_table` is not a `dict` at all but a list of tuples. What does `print(type(hash_table))` tell you?